# How to remove listner in the right way in react native navigation with class components

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-navigation

when I use `removeListner` function to remove the listner on navigation, I got a warning about that and that the remove not works correctly.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.addListener('focus', this.props.didFocus);
    this.props.navigation.addListener('blur', this.props.didBlur);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.navigation.removeListener('focus',this.props.didFocus);
    this.props.navigation.removeListener('blur',this.props.didBlur);
    }
  }
```

in old versions of Navigation it was used like the  following example :

```
 subscribe : NavigationEventSubscription;

 componentDidMount() {
   this.subscribe = this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', this.props.didFocus);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if(this.subscribe){
     this.subscribe.remove();
}
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`removeListener` works fine.

> I got a warning about that

You need to say what warning you got if you're asking for help.

Another way is to use the function returned by `addListener`.

```js
  unsubscribe?: () => void;

  componentDidMount() {
   this.unsubscribe = this.props.navigation.addListener('focus', this.props.didFocus);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe?.()
  }
```

Comment: what's the meaning of this `this.unsubscribe?.()`

Comment: that's the property added inside `componentDidMount`. are you asking about the optional chaining operator? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: the second function in the `componentWillUnmount` will not remove the listner as I guess, I m asking for the right way to remove the lisnert after using it to listen on the `componentDidMount` as in the example

Comment: > as I guess - ok so what do you guess that "unsubscribe" does...

Comment: do you mean it's compared to `this.props.navigation.removeLisner('focus', this.props.didFocus);`? cause this line is the solution and no need to use the unsbscribe variable any more

Comment: I already said that'll work fine (it's the same code that you wrote in your question and said that it doesn't work), and what I posted is another way. I'm not sure what you're asking